# Enviar imagen en base64 a un API y descodificarla para procesarla en este

Tags: json, imagen, base64

estoy implementando un API en flask de reconocimiento facial, y necesito que reciba una imagen codificada en base64, la decodifique para procesarla. En el cliente envio la imagen con este codigo

```
cv2.imwrite('imagen.jpg', frame)
img= open('imagen.jpg', 'rb')
frame = img.read()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    response = requests.post('http://localhost:5001/server/recognice', json={'imagen': str(base64.b64encode(frame))}).json()
```

Pero al recibirla en el microservicio, con este codigo:

```
imgbase64 = request.json["imagen"]
frame = base64.b64decode(imgbase64)
```

#La variable frame sigue siendo tipo de datos bytes, por lo que no permite procesarla como imagen, Alguien me puede decir, que hacer para tratarla como imagen luego de recibirla en el microservicio. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resuelto, lo que habia que hacer es, en vez de castear a string en la oeticion del cliente, utilizar el metodo decode('utf-8') en la imagen codificada y enviarla de esta forma, una vez en el servidor, utilizar el método encode('utf-8') para llevarla de nuevo a bytes, y luego decodificarla en base 64.